# How to write a test script to validate the validation dataset and testing dataset for pytorch YOLOv4?

Tags: python, pytorch, object-detection, yolov5, yolov4

I am currently following this github repo: https://github.com/Tianxiaomo/pytorch-YOLOv4 to implement a pytorch YOLOv4 model. However, this repo did not provide **test.py/val.py**. We know that YOLOv5 does provide **val.py** which **purpose is to let us validate out trained result on validation dataset and testing dataset**.

So **I want to write a test.py/val.py** for this purpose, but I am have really no idea how to write. Anyone have experience on how to write, can you please share some idea to write it?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [YOLOv4-Scaled official repo](https://github.com/WongKinYiu/ScaledYOLOv4), they use official pycocotools API for evaluation.